# Three Jordan curves made from paths

Tags: general-topology

For continuous paths $\phi,\psi:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\phi(1)=\psi(0)$, let $\phi*\psi$ denote the composition path and $\phi^{-1}$ the inverse path.

Consider points $p,q\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and paths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\gamma_i(0)=p$ and $\gamma_i(1)=q$. Assume that the loops $\gamma_1*\gamma_2^{-1}, \gamma_1*\gamma_3^{-1}, \gamma_2*\gamma_3^{-1}$ are all simple closed curves (i.e. Jordan curves). From the Jordan curve theorem, it follows that each of these loops has a (bounded) interior and an (unbounded) exterior.

I would like to know how to make a rigorous proof (or see a counterexample, which I don't think exists) of the following easy-looking statement: one of the paths $\gamma_i$ lies in the interior of the Jordan curve $\gamma_j*\gamma_k^{-1}$ made from the other two paths.

Comment: What is meant by lies in the interior, what about if the paths intersect the other paths?

Comment: @TonyS.F. Paths cannot intersect other paths because I required loops made from each pair of paths to be Jordan curves. By interior I mean the one you get from the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: @MarcoFlores Suppose none of the paths lies in the interior of the Jordan curve made by the other two. Then either each of them lies in the exterior of the other two, or hits both the interior and exterior. If $\gamma_i$ lies in the exterior of $\gamma_j^{-1}  *\gamma_k^{-1}$, then $\gamma_j$ sits inside $\gamma_i * \gamma_k^{-1}$, so the first case cannot happen. If $\gamma_i$ hits the circle $\gamma_j * \gamma_k^{-1}$ on any pt except $p, q$ (suppose it hits $\gamma_j$ WLOG), then $\gamma_i * \gamma_j^{-1}$ is not a simple hence not a Jordan curve.

Comment: @BalarkaSen why does $\gamma_j$ sit inside $\gamma_i*\gamma_k^{-1}$?

Comment: Otherwise the graph $K_{3,3}$ would be planar, but it is not, see http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2011/10/29/why-the-complete-bipartite-graph-k33-is-not-planar/. Curiously, results of this type go under the umbrella of Van Kampen - Flores theorem. Are you related?